# When I use the flutter doctor command to check the status, it says plugins for flutter and dart are not installed

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am done with my installation and all but then also it's showing that SDK took missing but in the android studio, I did all the requirements that were must be installed.

Also, plugins are installed but then also after I use the flutter doctor command to know the status it's showing plugin not installed for flutter and dart.
Please try to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

go to file->settings->Language & Frameworks

- select dart and choose your dart sdk location
- select flutter and select your flutter sdk location